# Hardware Keyboard support for several language [WIN CE 6.0 CF]

Tags: keyboard, windows-ce

I'm currently working on a platform with WinCE 6.0 R3 Compact Framework.
I change the settings in the register to different culture and different language layouts.
This works for the text, time, date, etc.
But when I connect a USB hardware keyboard only three languages are supported:
USA, Korea, and Japan.

I want some other languages as well like Finish, Swedish, Germany, etc.

Guess I need drivers? How do I solve this? Feels like I'm not the first one going down this path.

Comment: When im suppost to build my drivers DLL i get following error. Need help. Error 5 U1033: syntax error : '$(_PROJECTROOT)\cesysgen\sdk\lib\$(_CPUINDPATH)\coredll.lib' unexpected C:\WINCE600\public\common\oak\drivers\keybd\dll\KBD8042SW\sources 37 
Error 6 BUILD: [01:0000000021:ERRORE] NMAKE.EXE WinceTargetFile0 -i -c BUILDMSG=Stop. BUILDROOT=C:\WINCE600\public\common NOLINK=1 PASS0ONLY=1 failed - rc = 2

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the keyboard driver's key map to include the other keyboards.  I had to do this probably a decade ago for Finnish on CE 5.0, so I don't recall all of the details but I do know it was a simple change to the layout map and it took very little actual time to fix.  It did, however, require a recompile of the driver and the OS.  [MSDN has pointers to the drive location for where the current layouts, etc. are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms892478.aspx).

Comment: Guess i need some more explanation. I have added all wanted languages but when i attach a Swedish keyboard for example it doesnt work since the language code for SWE-se isnt mapped with any drivers. WinCE 6.0 using kbdmouse.dll but this only include the 3 mention before language. Guess i need a new kbdmouse.dll file with all wanted language? Or am i wrong here?

Comment: Think i figured out that i need DeviceLayout files for each keyboard. Does that ring a bell?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guide and think it worked out:

http://ethanchen1108.pixnet.net/blog/post/6143102-%E2%97%8E-create-french-keyboard-layout-for-windows-ce